# WORHP - Matlab and AMPL interfaces

Tags: worhp

I have just downloaded and installed WORHP in my Linux machine. However, it is just not clear to me how to use either the AMPL and Matlab interfaces. The User's guide says that .mex files and the AMPL binary should be provided together with the installation, but I cannot find it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the long delay of my answer. We just released WORHP 1.13 where we again included AMPL and Matlab, see [worhp.de](https://www.worhp.de/). For Matlab you need to download a further ZIP package that you can find in the downloading section together with further instructions. The AMPL interface will be installed with the Ubuntu etc. builds to `/usr/bin/worhp_ampl`.